# Views Path Settings is not redirecting to particular path?

Tags: 7, views

I have been working on drupal 7.54 version.

I have created on sample view and trying to display the view in particular path.

[image]

Here, I have mentioned the path as comment-count, but its not getting redirected to the path, because its taking as query string.

How can I change this thing.

Is there any problem in latest instance or else guide me how to sort out this problem?

Comment: looks like you need to enable clean urls at `/admin/config/search/clean-urls`

Comment: okay I will enable it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to /admin/config/search/clean-urls and enable the clean urls.

[image]

Then try these steps If clean Url test is failed.
enable mod_rewrite apache from httpd.conf

1. open httpd.conf
2. find mod_rewrite
3. just remove # to enable
4. once it enable then you can run Clean URL
5. this will show check box tick on it and save it

Comment: Yeah, but its showing cleaning url is failed

Comment: I have edit my answer. Please review.

Comment: Yeah Its working now